# Empty array is false, but in IF statement it returns true

Tags: javascript, arrays

This returns true:

```
[] == false
```

But here, alert is called:

```
if([]){ alert('empty array is true here'); }
```

Can you explain why?

Comment: Inspired by the question you answered recently, hu? :)

Comment: @dfsq yes, you are right :D

Comment: Good question, but don't be confused with what's being compared in both cases. Check the link prvided by @Kobi.

Comment: Similar: `[1] == 1`, `[[1]] == 1`, `[1] != [[1]]`, `[1] != [1]`.

Comment: @Kobi thanks for link provided, I'm reading it now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is because `==` in JS forces conversion and if one type can be converted to another the return value is `true` and here because `[]` cant be changed or compared with bool it is false 
where as `if([])` checks for `null` and `undefined` values and because [] is neither null or undefined it is returning true

check this 
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: "== forces conversion" isn't strictly true; also, `if` checks for more than just `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 15):

According to [section 11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) of the [ECMAScript® Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), any `==` comparison is done as follows:

1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then

   1. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
   2. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
   3. If Type(x) is Number, then

      1. If x is NaN, return false.
      2. If y is NaN, return false.
      3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
      4. If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
      5. If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
      6. Return false.
   4. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions). Otherwise, return false.
   5. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false. Otherwise, return false.
   6. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.
2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
   return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
   return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
7. **If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).**
8. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object,
   return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
9. **If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
   return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.**
10. Return false.

In the first step, [`ToNumber()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) is applied to `false` and yields `Number(0)`. In the second step, rule #9 applies [`ToPrimitive()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) to the empty array and yields `""` which, cast to a numeric value, becomes `Number(0)` as well.

Additionally [section 9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) says this about using an object in an expression:

> The abstract operation `ToBoolean` converts its argument to a value of type Boolean according to this table:

- Undefined -> false
- Null -> false
- Boolean -> The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
- Number -> The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
- String -> The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
- **Object -> true**