# How to get the title of a Google Calendar's event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to parse the entries in a Google Calendar feed but so far I haven't been able to retrieve the title, I was hoping someone would give me a suggestion. From what I see in firebug I can't understand why the following is not working, since I loop through the entries with the each method like follows:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/cide.edu_sm151i2pdhu2371vq8hamcver4@group.calendar.google.com/public/full?q="+encodeURI($(this).val()), {"alt" : "json"}, function(data) {
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, entry) {
        var key = entry.gd$when[0].startTime.substr(0, 10);
        if(key in SelectedDates == false) {
            SelectedDates[key] = [];    
        }
        else {
            var titulo = escape(this.title.$t);
            SelectedDates[key].push(titulo);    
        }
    });
});
```

I define SelectedDates as an array earlier, but whenever I make the request, the SelectedDates array contains the keys alright, but only blank arrays in them, like follows: `2014-02-04    []` I wish I could grasp how to pass the title of the event to the object.

Comment: You are using Calendar v2 API which was deprecated 3 years ago and was announced to shutdown on November 17th. Consider migrating to the new version: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in javascript an empty array == false.

Change this:

```
if(key in SelectedDates == false) {
```

to

```
if(key in SelectedDates === false) {
```

EDIT:

empty arrays are not falsey but do equate to false when explicitly checked

https://medium.com/@daffl/javascript-the-weird-parts-8ff3da55798e

Comment: I believe an empty array is truthy. If you type this in your JS console in Chrome, it will spit out "truthy": if ([]) { console.log('truthy'); }

Comment: try `[] == false` in your console

Comment: Now you've stumped me. [] == false does indeed result as true in JS console, but, if ([]) { console.log('truthy'); } renders "truthy".

Comment: I see that too. Very strange behavior!

Comment: Many thanks, it worked, I also realized that the logic was wrong in my code, I had to remove the else statement and leave it only in `var titulo = escape(this.title.$t);
SelectedDates[key].push(titulo);` for it to work

Comment: @IanDavis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240452/empty-array-is-false-but-in-if-statement-it-returns-true - this is why apparently